# How to rescue an eval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, eval, rescue

I'm trying to figure out how to rescue syntax errors that come up when `eval()`ing code in Ruby 1.8.6.

I would expect the following Ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

good_str = "(1+1)"
bad_str = "(1+1"    # syntax error: missing closing paren

begin
    puts eval(good_str)
    puts eval(bad_str)
rescue => exc
    puts "RESCUED!"
end
```

to produce the following result when run:

```
2
RESCUED!
```

Instead, what I get is:

```
2
eval_rescue.rb:8: (eval):1: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

It appears that the SyntaxError raised by the eval method is being rescued somewhere within the eval, without giving me a chance to handle it myself.

Anybody have any idea how to get the behavior I want (i.e., for my 'rescue' clause to catch the error from the 'eval')?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, that was easy...

It turns out that, by default, the "rescue" statement does not catch **all** exceptions, but only those that are subclasses of StandardError.  SyntaxError is a sibling/cousin of StandardError, not a subclass of it, so the rescue statement doesn't capture it unless explicitly told to.

To have the rescue block capture **all** exceptions, you need to change the code to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

good_str = "(1+1)"
bad_str = "(1+1"    # syntax error: missing closing paren

begin
    puts eval(good_str)
    puts eval(bad_str)
rescue Exception => exc
    puts "RESCUED!"
end
```

Note the change in the "rescue" line, from "rescue => exc" to "rescue Exception => exc".

Now, when you run the code, you get the desired results:

```
2
RESCUED!
```

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby

Answer (score 51):

Brent already got an [answer that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542845/how-to-rescue-an-eval-in-ruby/542857#542857), but I recommend rescuing from the smallest set of exceptions you can get away with.  This makes sure you're not accidentally gobbling up something you don't mean to be.

Thus,

```
begin
  puts eval(good_str)
  puts eval(bad_str)
rescue SyntaxError => se
  puts 'RESCUED!'
end
```

Comment: This is good advice. For example, rescuing Exception rather than SyntaxError will prevent you interrupting your process with a ctrl-C.

Comment: I am surprised this has not caught on more as a best practice.