# Begin and Rescue block exception handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have little experience in rails exception handling. I have this snippet

```
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  begin
    params[:game][:tier] = eval(params[:game][:tier]) 
  rescue 
    @game.errors.add(:tier, "Please make sure the correct format for tier, example [100, 1000, 10000]")
  end
#.... more code
end
```

In case params[:game][:tier] = "[100,200]" everything is perfect.
In case of error case of ruby syntax like params[:game][:tier] = "[100,200] abc" it catch the error however the application just crush.

How can I handle exception with 'eval()' such that it won't crush the app? Why begin and rescue does not work in this case? Appreciate any help for ruby enlightenment thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if `params[:game][:tier]` was `"[100,200]; system('rm -rf /')"`?

Since the incoming data is expected to be an array, I would not use `eval` but `JSON.parse` instead:

```
> JSON.parse("[100,200]")
 => [100, 200]
> JSON.parse("[100,200] abc")
JSON::ParserError: 746: unexpected token at 'abc'...
```

Then rescue from only a `JSON::ParserError` exception

```
rescue JSON::ParserError => e
```

This will also solve the rescue not catching the exception problem you're having.

Comment: Wow, this is dangerous injection. Lot of thanks, and JSON.parse does work really well. :D

Comment: And once again proof that (in most cases) `eval` is evil and can be replaced with something way better.

Answer (score 1):

duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542845/how-to-rescue-an-eval-in-ruby/542857#542857)

however you should rescue in this way

```
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  begin
    params[:game][:tier] = eval(params[:game][:tier]) 
  rescue Exception => e
    @game.errors.add(:tier, "Please make sure the correct format for tier, example [100, 1000, 10000]")
  end
#.... more code
```

end

in order to make it work

Comment: never, ever rescue Exception

Comment: Agree, rescue `StandardError` instead. Source: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception