# Get line number of beginning and end of Ruby method given a ruby file

Tags: ruby

How can I find the line of the beginning and end of a Ruby method given a ruby file?

Say for example:

```
1 class Home
2   def initialize(color)
3     @color = color
4   end
5 end
```

Given the file `home.rb` and the method name `initialize` I would like to receive (2,4) which are the beginning and end lines.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the `end` is tricky. The best way I can think of is to use the [parser gem](https://github.com/whitequark/parser). Basically you'll parse the Ruby code into an AST, then recursively traverse its nodes until you find a node with type `:def` whose first child is `:initialize`:

```
require "parser/current"

def recursive_find(node, &block)
  return node if block.call(node)
  return nil unless node.respond_to?(:children) && !node.children.empty?
  node.children.each do |child_node|
    found = recursive_find(child_node, &block)
    return found if found
  end
  nil
end

src = <<END
  class Home
    def initialize(color)
      @color = color
    end
  end
END
ast = Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(src)

found = recursive_find(ast) do |node|
  node.respond_to?(:type) && node.type == :def && node.children[0] == :initialize
end

puts "Start: #{found.loc.first_line}"
puts "End: #{found.loc.last_line}"

# => Start: 2
#    End: 4
```

P.S. I would have recommended the [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) module from the standard library, but as far as I can tell there's no way to get the end line out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a `source_location` method which gives you the file and the beginning line:

```
class Home
  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end
end

p Home.new(1).method(:initialize).source_location
# => ["test2.rb", 2]
```

To find the end, perhaps look for the next `def` or EOF.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, there might be constructs following the `end` that terminates the definition of  `initialize` that end with a line `end` but do not begin with `def`. Two examples are `define_method(:dog); do; "woof"; end` and `p = -> do; "woof"; end`.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby source is nothing but a text file. You can use linux commands to find the method line number

```
grep -nrw 'def initialize' home.rb | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```

Comment: OP asked how to find the beginning *and* end of the method. How would you find the `end`, given that a file/class/method may have any number of `end`s?

Comment: @Jordan, maybe by looking at the indentation? Assuming that code indented properly :)

Comment: Yep, problem is finding the end line :)

Comment: Wounder if you could count the `if`, `do`, `while` and other blocks. To know which `end` to get the line number of

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the file contains the definition of at most one `initialize` method (though generalizing the method to search for others would not be difficult) and that the definition of that method contains no syntax errors. The latter assumption is probably required for any method to extract the correct line range.

The only tricky part is finding the line containing `end` that is the last line of the definition of the `initialize` method. I've used [Kernel#eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) to locate that line. Naturally caution must be exercised whenever that method is to be executed, though here `eval` is merely attempting to compile (not execute) a method.

**Code**

```
def get_start_end_offsets(fname)
  start = nil
  str = ''
  File.foreach(fname).with_index do |line, i|
    if start.nil?
      next unless line.lstrip.start_with?('def initialize')
      start = i
      str << line.lstrip.insert(4,'_')
    else
      str << line
      if line.strip == "end"
        begin
          rv = eval(str)
        rescue SyntaxError
          nil
        end
        return [start, i] unless rv.nil? 
      end
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

**Example**

Suppose we are searching a file created as follows<sup>1</sup>.

```
str = <<-_
class C
  def self.feline
    "cat"
  end
  def initialize(arr)
    @row_sums = arr.map do |row|
      row.reduce do |t,x|
        t+x
      end
    end
  end
  def speak(sound)
    puts sound
  end
end
_

FName = 'temp'
File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 203
```

We first search for the line that begins (after stripping leading spaces) `"def initialize"`. That is the line at index `4`. The `end` that completes the definition of that method is at index `10`. We therefore expect the method to return `[4, 10]`.

Let's see if that's what we get.

```
p get_start_end_offsets(FName)
  #=> [4, 10]
```

**Explanation**

The variable `start` equals the index of the line beginning `def initialize` (after removing leading whitespace). `start` is initially `nil` and remains `nil` until the `"def initialize"` line is found. `start` is then set to the index of that line.

We now look for a line `line` such that `line.strip #=> "end"`. This may or may not be the `end` that terminates the method. To determine if it is we `eval` a string that contains all lines from the one that begins `def initialize` to the line equal to `end` just found. If `eval` raises a `SyntaxError` exception that `end` does not terminate the method. That exception is rescued and `nil` is returned. `eval` will return `:_initialize` (which is truthy) if that `end` terminates the method. In that case the method returns `[start, i]`, where `i` is the index of that line. `nil` is returned if no `initialize` method is found in the file.

I've converted `"initialize"` to `"_initialize"` to suppress the warning  `(eval):1: warning: redefining Object#initialize may cause infinite loop`)

See both answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542845/how-to-rescue-an-eval-in-ruby) to understand why `SyntaxError` is being rescued.

**Compare indentation**

If it is known that `"def initialize..."` is always indented the same amount as the line `"end"` that terminates the method definition (and no other lines `"end"` between the two are indented the same), we can use that fact to obtain the beginning and ending lines. There are many ways to do that; I will use Ruby's somewhat obscure [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) operator. This approach will tolerate syntax errors.

```
def get_start_end_offsets(fname)
  indent = -1
  lines = File.foreach(fname).with_index.select do |line, i|
    cond1 = line.lstrip.start_with?('def initialize')
    indent = line.size - line.lstrip.size if cond1
    cond2 = line.strip == "end" && line.size - line.lstrip.size == indent
    cond1 .. cond2 ? true : false
  end
  return nil if lines.nil?
  lines.map(&:last).minmax
end

get_start_end_offsets(FName)
  #=> [4, 10]
```

<sup>1 The file need not contain only code.</sup>